# Average in 'For' loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have some issue in this code where my `.Value` wouldn't work.

Everything works fine if I do a hardcode my ->>> .Value = "=Average(E2:E7)"

However when I do the following below, it will not work. I'm sure it's the --> range("E" ........)

```
'Iterate average for close price per week
Dim startOfWeek As Integer
Dim endOfWeek As Integer

numberOfWeek = 52
startOfWeek = 2
endOfWeek = 6
secondRow = 2

For i = 1 To numberOfWeek
    range("J" + CStr(secondRow)).Select
        With Selection





            .Value = "=Average(" + range("E" + CStr(startOfWeek) + ":E" + CStr(endOfWeek)).Select + ")"




            .Font.Bold = False
        End With
    secondRow = secondRow + 1
    startOfWeek = startOfWeek + 5
    endOfWeek = endOfWeek + 5
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No need to add `CStr` when referencing the row number. You can remove them all.
2. You can get rid of all select statements and work directly with the object.

So you can refactor your code like this:

```
'Iterate average for close price per week
Dim startOfWeek As Integer
Dim endOfWeek As Integer

numberOfWeek = 52
startOfWeek = 2
endOfWeek = 6
secondRow = 2

For i = 1 To numberOfWeek

     With Range("J" & secondRow)

        .Value = "=Average(E" & startOfWeek & ":E" & endOfWeek & ")"
        .Font.Bold = False

     End With

    secondRow = secondRow + 1
    startOfWeek = startOfWeek + 5
    endOfWeek = endOfWeek + 5

Next i
```

Comment: Thanks however it is in red color and the error is "Expected: end of statement"

Comment: Oh I have realize that there is a missing "&" .

Comment: .Value = "=Average(E" & CStr(startOfWeek) & ":E" & CStr(endOfWeek) & ")"

Comment: good catch. I made some edits to my answer as well to assist you. if you it solves your question, please mark as answered :)